# Multiple entries in /etc/cifspw

Tags: samba

I'm trying to mount windows shares from ubuntu. Every tutorial tells me to store crendentials for the shares into the /etc/cifspw file. This is very good and works very well for a single windows share.

I'm trying to add another share from another machine with different credentials. How is this posible? Is there some kind of secret format for cifspw allowing multiple entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple entries in a single cifspw file, but you can override the file the cifs kernel module reads by specifying the 'credentials=FILE' option when mounting. See "man mount.cifs" for details.

E.g. to mount while reading credentials from /tmp/foo:

```
mount -o credentials=/tmp/foo -t cifs //host/bar /media/bar
```